# What determines order of printed results when counting with two threads?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

When counting with two threads as shown in the example below, what causes the order of the resulting sequence of numbers that are printed out? Sometimes the first thread counts 123 before the second thread starts, sometimes the first goes 1 and then the second goes 1234, what is the cause of this behaviour? What stops it from counting 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4... etc?

```
import threading

def count_to_ten():
    for i in range(1,11):
        print(i,end="")

x = threading.Thread(target=count_to_ten)
x.start()

y = threading.Thread(target=count_to_ten)
y.start()

x.join()
y.join()
```

Comment: There is no guarantee how much thread will process each interval it gets.  In fact, because you started x before y, it might complete entirely before y even gets started.  If you need throttling or synchronization between two threads, you have to program it in.

Comment: Threading in Python has been likened to cooperative multi-tasking where the threads take turns executing — they don't actually execute concurrently. Unless a thread does certain things such as an I/O operation or calls `time.sleep()`, the switching between them occurs under control of the interpreter, which I believe does so after a certain number of bytecode instructions get processed by each thread.

Answer (score 0):

From Real Python's [An Intro to Threading in Python](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/#what-is-a-thread):

> A thread is a separate flow of execution. This means that your program will have two things happening at once. But for most Python 3 implementations the different threads do not actually execute at the same time: they merely appear to.
>
> It’s tempting to think of threading as having two (or more) different processors running on your program, each one doing an independent task at the same time. That’s almost right. The threads may be running on different processors, but they will only be running one at a time. ...

So basicly you can not have an input such as `1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4` simply because the threads do not run at the same time.

However, you can achieve that result by adding a simply `sleep` function in order to synchronize the `print`s.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I am aware the variation is determined by the thread allocation and other aspects such as current CPU workload.

Below is some code that I have been using for multiprocessing, maybe it will be of some use for you.

```
import concurrent.futures

def SomeFunction():
    ProcessList = []
    for i in range(1,11):
        ProcessList.append(i)
    return ProcessList

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as exec:
         # loop determines the number of processes to run
         results = [exec.submit(SomeFunction) for _ in range(2)]

    for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
        r = f.result()
        print(r)
```

Output is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

If you need to use multi **threading** over multi **processing**, you can swap out
 `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()`
with
`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()`

Another note is this video which might give you some more details on the topic:
https://youtu.be/fKl2JW_qrso